# How can I use Ctrl+A / Ctrl+E in Microsoft Office Online to navigate to Start of line / End of line?

Tags: word-online, office-online

As a power user, I'm used to being able to quickly navigate to the start of a line or field with Control+A / Control+E. This happens in Mac OS X (Cocoa) apps, in terminal programs, and even in Web pages, for many different Web browsers.

However, Microsoft Office Online uses a fancy front-end UI that doesn't respect this convention. Is there a Microsoft Office Online setting or Web browser plugin that I can use to fix this keymapping?

For reference, I'm using Microsoft Word Online, in Google Chrome 40, on Mac OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite.

Comment: Not an answer, but you can try using Home and End (keys on a standard PC keyboard); on your Mac try **Home**: Fn + ←, **End**: Fn + →  Onlien settings would fall into the WebApps area, which is off-topic, and asking for a plug0-in falls into the Product Recommendation area, which is also off-topic.  To avoid it being closed for those reasons, perhaps edit your question to be less specific about asking for a plug-in, and include what you have tried so far (keyboard remap utility? - there's lots out there). But IMO this should be migrated to WebApps.

Comment: Yes, please move my question to the most appropriate SO area.

Comment: Have a look at this https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Word-Online-4ccbb899-f71e-4206-be6f-1d30c7d1bd13